# Why would a python regex compile on Linux but not Windows?

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex to detect invalid xml 1.0 characters in a unicode string:

```
bad_xml_chars = re.compile(u'[^\x09\x0A\x0D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\U00010000-\U0010FFFF]', re.U)
```

On Linux/python2.7, this works perfectly. On windows the following is raised:

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
  sre_constants.error: bad character range
```

Any ideas why this isn't compiling on Windows?

Comment: I get the same error on Linux (also Python 2.7).

Comment: Works here on Linux, Python 2.7

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a [narrow Python build](http://wordaligned.org/articles/narrow-python) on Windows, so Unicode uses [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).  This means that Unicode characters higher than `\uFFFF` will be two separate characters in the Python string.  You should see something like this:

```
>>> len(u'\U00010000')
2
>>> u'\U00010000'[0]
u'\ud800'
>>> u'\U00010000'[1]
u'\udc00'
```

Here is how the regex engine will attempt to interpret your string on narrow builds:

```
[^\x09\x0A\x0D\u0020-\ud7ff\ue000-\ufffd\ud800\udc00-\udbff\udfff]
```

You can see here that `\udc00-\udbff` is where the invalid range message is coming from.

Comment: This should be fixed in Python 3.3 - all builds will behave like wide builds (except using less memory). I appreciate it may not be feasible for the OP to use 3.3.

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't work because the Windows version of Python uses 16 bits to represent unicode characters, encoded as UTF-16. Code points `10000` and above are represented as two code units in UTF-16, and this confuses the `re` range representation which expects a single character on either side of the `-`.

This is how the string you're passing to `re.compile` is split into characters:

```
>>> [x for x in u'[^\x09\x0A\x0D\u0020-\uD7FF\uE000-\uFFFD\U00010000-\U0010FFFF]']
[u'[', u'^', u'\t', u'\n', u'\r', u' ', u'-', u'\ud7ff', u'\ue000', u'-', 
 u'\ufffd', u'\ud800', u'\udc00', u'-', u'\udbff', u'\udfff', u']']
```

Note that `\U00010000-\U0010FFFF` is represented as 5 characters:

```
u'\ud800', u'\udc00', u'-', u'\udbff', u'\udfff'
```

Inside the character set `[...]`, `re.compile` interprets this as the characters `u'\ud800'` and `u'\udfff'`, and the range `u'\udc00' - u'\udbff'`. This range is invalid because its end is smaller than its start, which causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

There's a section in the standard library that deals with bad character ranges (`Lib/sre_compile.py:450`):

```
if code1[0] != LITERAL or code2[0] != LITERAL:
    raise error, "bad character range"
lo = code1[1]
hi = code2[1]
if hi < lo:
    raise error, "bad character range"
```

When it compares the `lo` and `hi` literals of your `\U00010000-\U0010FFFF` character range, they come out to being ordinals `56320` and `56319`, respectively (which of course fails, because the range appears to be backwards).

As others have said, this is because Python is treating your 8-character Unicode literals as two separate characters.