# Emoji not detected with python regular expression in Linux

Tags: python, regex, linux, anaconda, conda

I have a regular expression to detect emojis :

`emoji = u'(\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]|\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f\ude80-\udeff]|[\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF])'`

and I test with this command:
`re.match(emoji, u'\U0001f602', re.UNICODE) # ""`

The problem is that if finds a match in my macOs machine, but **not** on Linux Debian

Using ipython 4.0.1 and Python 2.7.11 Both from conda distribution.

Why the problem matchin on Linux ?

Comment: please edit your Q to show sample emojis that aren't being captured. Good luck.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865346/why-would-a-python-regex-compile-on-linux-but-not-windows

Comment: The problem is related with narrow build or not. But my point was to the fact that Anaconda have different builds depending on the system.
In any case, the only way is to have the two options, if the code is to be multi-system :
`emoji = u'[\U0001F300-\U0001F64F\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF]'
try:
    unicodeCompile(emoji)
except:
    emoji = u'(\ud83c[\udf00-\udfff]|\ud83d[\udc00-\ude4f\ude80-\udeff]|[\u2600-\u26FF\u2700-\u27BF])'
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Mac OS has a [narrow python build](http://wordaligned.org/articles/narrow-python). Try this on it:

```
unichr(0x0001f602)
```

I expect you'll get an exception. It means that your Mac python install is treating unicode characters above FFFF as two characters.

```
>>> u'\ud83d\ude02'.encode('utf8')
'\xf0\x9f\x98\x82'

>>> u'\U0001f602'.encode('utf8')
'\xf0\x9f\x98\x82'

>>> re.match(emoji, u'\ud83d\ude02', re.UNICODE)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7fdf7405d6c0>
```

Notice how \ud83d\ude02 and \U0001f602 produce the same bytes. Your Mac OS is treating the character \U0001f602 as the two 8 hex digits \ud83d\ude02, which matches your regex. Linux is treating it as a single 16 hex digit, which doesn't match any of the ranges in your regex.

Your options are: 1) add the following range of characters to your regex under Linux:

ur'[\U0001F600-\U0001F64F]'

But it will break the regex under Mac OS, as per [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13865346/why-would-a-python-regex-compile-on-linux-but-not-windows)

2) switch to Python 3.

3) rebuild your python on Mac with the --enable-unicode=ucs4 option.